# Well-Formedness check in Enterprise Architect on UML profile

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, well-formed

I have created my own UML profil with new stereotyps in Enterprise Architect and made up some basic rules how these new stereotypes have to be connected. Now I'd like to have something like a Well-Formedness check on the models which I create.

I found that there is a Model Validation with some basic UML Well-Formedness checks, but I didn't find out how I can create my own rules, which should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

To create your own model validation rules, you have to write an Add-In.

Check the help file under Automation - Add-In Model - Broadcast Events - Model Validation Broadcasts. There's an example in there.

If you've never written an Add-In, check out [Geert Bellekens' blog](http://geertbellekens.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/tutorial-create-your-first-c-enterprise-architect-addin-in-10-minutes/) (not me) for a good quick-start introduction.